# makefile needs to be called twice

Tags: c++, makefile

I have this makefile below. While it compiles properly at the moment, I'm running into a really weird and tedious issue where I have to run `make` twice to compile the code.

The first time I call `make`, I get this error:

```
./src/gravity.cpp:1:31: fatal error: gravity.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I have a lot more source files added under `OBJECTS = ..`, and that message repeats for each one of them. Of course, this would indicate that I didn't link the headers correctly, except that when I run `make` again, everything compiles smoothly.

An interesting observation may be that `main.cpp` doesn't complain about a missing `gravity.h`, but I'm not sure how it relates.

I have header guards on all my header files. If it helps, this is for a C++ SDL/OpenGL application.

My makefile is below. Thanks!

```
OUTPUT_NAME = output_file
INC_DIR = ./inc
SRC_DIR = ./src
BIN_DIR = ./bin

INCLUDES= \
    -I${SRC_DIR}

SRC := $(shell find $(SRC_DIR) -name '*.cpp')
INC := $(shell find $(INC_DIR) -name '*.h')

CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -g -Wall -std=c++0x -I${INC_DIR} -I./lib/glm

LIBFLAGS = -lSDL -lGL -lGLU -lglut

OBJECTS = \
    ${BIN_DIR}/main.o \
    ${BIN_DIR}/gravity.o

DEPS = $(BIN_DIR)/${OUTPUT_NAME}.deps

all: ${DEPS} ${OUTPUT_NAME}

${DEPS}: ${INC} ${SRC}
    @${CXX} -M ${SRC} > ${DEPS}

${OUTPUT_NAME}: ${OBJECTS}
    ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} ${OBJECTS} -o ${OUTPUT_NAME} ${LIBFLAGS}

${OBJECTS}: ${BIN_DIR}/%.o : ${SRC_DIR}/%.cpp
    ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} $< -c -o $@

force:
    $(MAKE) fullclean
    $(MAKE)

clean:
    rm ${OBJECTS} ${OUTPUT_NAME}

fullclean:
    rm ${OBJECTS} ${DEPS} ${OUTPUT_NAME}

run:
    clear
    ./${OUTPUT_NAME}

style:
    astyle --style=java --indent=spaces=4 ${SRC} ${INC}

.PHONY: all clean fullclean run style force

include $(DEPS)
```

Comment: Are people still using make! Gradle or SCONS are better

Comment: Yes, lots of people still use `make`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Oh dear. Guess some have not heard on this new fangled machine the horse less carriage

Comment: The bicycle? I know what a bicycle is...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brass_Era_car

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule to build your `.deps` file:

```
${DEPS}: ${INC} ${SRC}
    @${CXX} -M ${SRC} > ${DEPS}
```

will unconditionally create the `${DEPS}` file even if the invocation of the C++ compiler fails. (It probably would have been better to have used `-o`.)

It is also missing the `-I` options which would allow it to find the header files.

As a result of the second error, it will fail when run. As a result of the first error, it will nevertheless create a .deps file. The second time you invoke `make`, it will not trigger the `${DEPS}` rule because the `.deps` file is newer than any dependency.

---

Also, I don't understand

```
INCLUDES= \
    -I${SRC_DIR}
```

It's not correct (I think: it should be `INC_DIR`, and it's missing `./lib/glm`), and you don't use it anywhere.

Comment: Awesome! I cleaned up my DEPS and OUTPUT_NAME rules and fixed the INCLUDES variable (I'm not sure what I was thinking there), and it seems to have fixed the compiling errors. It takes a bit longer to run, but it doesn't fail once then work the next time, which was absolutely annoying. Thanks a bunch!